# Python equivalent of PHP curl request

Tags: php, python, curl

I'm using Rauth for my queries to the Beatport API. I'm using this [working example in PHP](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beatport-api/sEpZUJkaSdo/tEXwt189m5sJ) as reference.

This PHP code below uses a request token to log in and authenticate for 3-legged auth

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
$submit = "Login";
$url = $auth_submiturl;

$curl_connection_bp = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT6.0; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11");
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false); // when true, this outputs the oauth_token and oauth_verifier value that are posted to the callback URL
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_REFERER, $curl_connection_bp);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
$post_string = 'oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token'] . '&username=' . $beatport_login . '&password=' . $beatport_password . '&submit=Login';
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection_bp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$beatport_response = curl_exec($curl_connection_bp);
$beatport_response = json_decode($beatport_response);

print_r($beatport_response);
```

How can I achieve this in Python? I think I need to use urllib, but I can't understand the PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use requests? http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/

This library should be able to do what this php code is doing easily.

Answer (score 4):

use pycurl it is a python implementation of lib curl.

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://www.python.org/")
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Accept:"])
...
```

you can find more examples and documentation here http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/curlobject.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use urlopen to issue requests.

A simple example:

```
import urllib2
result = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
print result.read()
```

Read more here:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Google urlopen code examples, and you will find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother trying to convert PHP code into python, but instead just search for a Python way of getting this answer. A little googling and it looks like this might be a duplicate:

[Oauth client initialization in python for tumblr API using Python-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569018/oauth-client-initialization-in-python-for-tumblr-api-using-python-oauth2)